# How to use for loop in the if statement?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm try to develop progress bar chart for road construction  using appscript. I have a tab for enter the form data.
[image: data entry form]

And in this file have more tabs for multiple roads names.
[image: multiple bar chart for road names]

It's like this
[image: bar chart interface]

This is what I am trying to do. After entering the data in the data entry form, colorize the cell range of the specified location in the relevant barchart.
This is where I first tried to find out where to start coloring. The following code was used for that.But running the "for loop" in the "if statement". But it does not happen successfully.

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp;
  var sheet=ss.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AddData");
  var actTabName = sheet.getRange("E1").getValue();
  var catName = sheet.getRange("B4").getValue();
  var start =sheet.getRange("B1").getValue();
  var end = sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var side = sheet.getRange("B3").getValue();
  function setBarChart() {
  var markTab = ss.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(actTabName);
  var lstRw = markTab.getLastRow();
  var lstCl = markTab.getLastColumn();

  Logger.log(lstRw);
  Logger.log(lstCl);

  var catList = markTab.getRange(1,3,lstRw-2,1).getValues();
  Logger.log(catList)

  for(var i=0; i<catList.length; i++){
  if(catList[i] == "Chainage"){
  var chRNo = i+1;
  
  var chList = markTab.getRange(chRNo,4,1,lstCl-3).getValues();     

   }
  }
  Logger.log("chRNo "+chRNo);  

 if(side == "LHS"){
 for(var j=0; j<8; j++){
  if(catList[i] == catName){
    var catLhRNo = j+1;
    Logger.log("catLhRNo = "+catLhRNo);
  
    }
    else{
    Logger.log("test1");
    }
    }
    }
    if(side == "RHS"){
    for (var k=8; k<11; k++){
    if(catList[0][k] == catName){
    var catRhRno = k+1;
    Logger.log("catRhRno = "+catRhRno);
    
    
    
    }else{
    Logger.log("test2");
    Logger.log(catList[7]);
    }
    }
    }  
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advice to break complicated operations into small simple functions:

```
function main() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('AddData');

  // get the data from the sheet 'AddData'
  var [start, end, side, item] = sheet.getRange('b1:b4').getValues().flat();
  var tab = ss.getSheetByName(sheet.getRange('e1').getValue());

  // get the row index from given sheet (tab), side and item
  var row = get_row(tab, side, item);

  // colorize the row on given sheet
  colorize_row(tab, row, start, end);
}

// get the row index
function get_row(tab, side, item) {
  var items = tab.getRange('b1:b11').getValues().flat();
  if (side == 'LHS') return items.indexOf(item) + 1;
  if (side == 'RHS') return items.lastIndexOf(item) + 1;
}

// colorize cells on the given tab and row
function colorize_row(tab, row, start, end) {
  var chainage = tab.getRange(6, 2, 1, tab.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();
  var start_index = chainage.indexOf(start) + 2;
  var end_index = chainage.indexOf(end) - start_index + 3;
  var color = tab.getRange('b' + row).getBackground();               // upd
  tab.getRange(row, start_index, 1, end_index).setBackground(color); // upd
}
```

**Update**

If you want to get row-index of 'Chainage' dynamically from B column you can change the function `colorize_row()` this way:

```
function colorize_row(tab, row, start, end) {
  var chainage_row = tab.getRange('b:b').getValues().flat().indexOf('Chainage') + 1;
  var chainage = tab.getRange(chainage_row, 2, 1, tab.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat();
  var start_index = chainage.indexOf(start) + 2;
  var end_index = chainage.indexOf(end) - start_index + 3;
  var color = tab.getRange('b' + row).getBackground();
  tab.getRange(row, start_index, 1, end_index).setBackground(color).mergeAcross();
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242747/discussion-on-answer-by-yuri-khristich-how-to-use-for-loop-in-the-if-statement).

Answer (score 0):

#### Try something like this:

```
function totalfunk() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("AddData");
  var catName = sh.getRange("B4").getValue();
  var side = sh.getRange("B3").getValue();
  var msh = ss.getSheetByName(sh.getRange("E1").getValue());
  var catList = msh.getRange(1, 3, msh.getLastRow() - 2, 1).getValues();
  const catList1 = catList.slice(0, 8);
  let i = catList.indexOf("Chainage")
  if (~i) {//much quicker than using loop
    var chRNo = i + 1;
    var chList = msh.getRange(chRNo, 4, 1, msh.getLastColumn() - 3).getValues();
  }
  let j = catList.indexOf(catName)''
  if (~j && side == LHS) {
    var catLhRNo = j + 1;
  }
  if (~j && side == RHS) {
    var catRhRno = j + 1;
  }
}
```

I would not expect this to work for you without some adjustments on your part

Comment: I tried to print the following variable. But it did not happen. chRNo, catLhRNo, catRhRno, chList. Why did that happen? And I'm not clear about using the "~". Can you explain it?

Comment: It's a bitwise not